# HTTPS Issue with redirecting

Tags: java, php, javascript

So I inserted a SLL Certificate and now in the code for the web.config file I have

Code:

```
<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="removed by me" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="(^OFF$)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

Now this works great and all but the directory that is what i use is site/folder/root(where all my files i need accessed are set to)  Now with the code I used when I go to lets say login and I am at site/folder/loginfile and I login, it takes me to site/loginsuccess file when it should be site/folder/root.

Please let me know if you need anything else!

Thank you!

EDITED-----------

My redirect once you successfully login is:

```
header("location:http://Site/folder/memberinterface.php");
```

Comment: It would help to know what web server you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

I need to change

`action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />` to

```
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

change

```
header("location:http://Site/folder/memberinterface.php");
```

to

```
header("location: http://Site/folder/memberinterface.php");
                 ^
                 ^
```

you have not inserted `space` this is causing problem.

Comment: Still takes me to site/loginsucess file when the file is located at site/folder/root.  It only happens when I enable the SLL redirect code.

Comment: why you want this line `<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />`

Comment: This is what they told us from win host.

Comment: This adds the https in front of the site but I'm feeling that is causing and issue.